# how to optimize the code to improve performance foreach loop in C#?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, optimization, c#-3.0, asp.net-apicontroller

Below functionality is taking more time iteration, It's required to optimize code to improve the Performance to fetch data . can you help me how to optimize ?

```
private List<ApplicationMenuItemDTO> toDTO(List<ApplicationMenuItem> list)
{
    if (list.Count() > 0)
    {
        ApplicationUser u = manager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId<int>());
        List<ApplicationMenuItemDTO> miDTOs = new List<ApplicationMenuItemDTO>();
        foreach(ApplicationMenuItem mi in list)
        {
            if (mi.PermissionId == null // menu items that do not require permission
                || u.HasPermission(mi.PermissionId)) // menu items user has permission to
            {
                miDTOs.Add(new ApplicationMenuItemDTO {
                    MenuItemId = mi.MenuItemId,
                    ParentMenuItemId = mi.ParentMenuItemId,
                    Name = mi.Name,
                    NamePlural = mi.NamePlural,
                    DisplayName = mi.DisplayName,
                    DisplayNamePlural = mi.DisplayNamePlural,
                    DeepLink = mi.DeepLink,
                    ApplicationPageId = mi.ApplicationPageId,
                    Description = mi.Description,
                    PermissionId = mi.PermissionId,
                    IsLocked = mi.IsLocked,
                    Url = mi.Url,
                    Rank = mi.Rank,
                    MenuItemTypeID = mi.MenuItemTypeID,
                    MenuItem = toDTO(db.ApplicationMenuItems.Where(x => x.ParentMenuItemId == mi.MenuItemId).ToList())
                });
            }
        }

        return miDTOs.OrderBy(x=>x.Rank).ToList();
    }
    else
    {
        //base case - return empty list
        return new List<ApplicationMenuItemDTO>();
    }
}
```

Comment: `return list.Where(a => a.PermissionId  == null || u.HasPermission(a.PermissionId)).OrderBy(b => b.Rank).ToList()`? Also, are you really using c# 3.0? That was released in 2007.

Comment: Not using c#3.0 by mistakenly added.. @RyanWilson

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to tell, because the OP doesn't write where the performance problems are, but here are a couple of guesses.

```
ApplicationUser u = manager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId<int>());
```

I can't tell whether this query is expensive, but on the other hand, it doesn't seem to rely on any `mi` data. Thus, you could move it out of the `foreach` loop.

This line of code:

```
MenuItem = toDTO(db.ApplicationMenuItems
    .Where(x => x.ParentMenuItemId == mi.MenuItemId)
    .ToList())
```

looks as though it performs a database query per loop iteration. Thus, if you have fifty items in `list`, you'd be performing fifty database queries.

Try to investigate whether you can move database queries out of the loop, and instead make a single bulk query. Then zip or join the result of that query with `list`.